# The c# of this JavaScript "regex replace"?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

**Javascript code**

```
    text = text
        .replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "")                
        .replace(/[,:;()\/&+]|\-\-/g, " ")
```

Would  it look something similar to this and would I have to make multiple regex object in order to do what is being done in JavaScript?

**C#**

```
        Regex r = new Regex("<[^>]+>");
        text = r.Replace(text, " ");
```

Comment: Did you test it? What was the result? Did it work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has a static method for matching for replacing a string treated as a pattern on the fly:

```
text = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(text, @"[^>]+", ""), @"[,:;()/&+]|--", " ");
```

The `Regex.Replace` method automatically does a global replace.